# Moving existing MVC4 project to Visual Studio Online

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-devops

I have a MVC4 project that I have been working on it alone. now I want to create a new Visual Studio Online account and move my project there so that I can add my new team members there and continue the development together.

any Ideas How to move existing project on my PC to Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest these steps :

1. Create your account on VS online
2. Create new Team Project on VS Online
3. Connect your project (local) with tab TEAM/CONNECT TO TFS from your Visual Studio using your VS online account.
4. Add files to the project solution ( and checkin)
5. Add emails of every team members under security tab of team project.

Tell me if you need something else.

Comment: Note: You can use every provider for emails of your team but must be trusted under Microsoft Account. To do this you must register the emails under outlook provider.